# Exoplayer in Android Studio: play video/audio instantly when uploading to a playlist

Tags: java, android-studio, exoplayer

I have several buttons (1, 2, 3...) that add corresponding videos from resources to the playlist, but these videos will only start playing when I click the triangular button "Play" in the middle of the screen. Is there a way to have a video play immediately automatically when it is added to a playlist?

[image]

```
// first button
        Video1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player.addMediaItem(firstItem); // add video in playList
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"1 video added to playlist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //playerS.addMediaItem(a_Item1);
                //playerS.prepare();
                //playerS.setPlayWhenReady(true);

                // Voice acting - plays synthesized mp3 sound in another Exo module
                playerS.setMediaItem(a_Item1);
                // Prepare the player.
                playerS.prepare();
                // Start the playback.
                playerS.play();

                PLstr += "1 ";
            }
        });

        // 2nd and 3rd buttons are the same ...
```